# Codename One - Log the RAM and Storage used by an app

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to Log.p("amount of Ram consumed"); by an app?

And Log.p("amount of Storage used"); by an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but not reliably. Devices are pretty problematic with RAM allocations per app as they sequester memory in ways that are very unclear. `Runtime.freeMemory` should work with the current iOS VM and produce "something" but I'm not sure how valuable that will be.

Keep in mind that the GC in all platforms will cause issues as there is no guarantee `System.gc()` will do anything or how long it will take to do whatever it is that isn't guaranteed...

If you want to check memory leaks in your app I suggest using a memory profiler on the desktop. The NetBeans one works great and you can see memory growing without shrinking if you have a memory issue. You can track it down to a specific memory leak very easily.

Comment: Do you refer to https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/nb-profiler-uncoveringleaks_pt1.html? Is a valid solution only for an app running in the Codename One SImulator? How can I monitor an app on a real device?

Comment: I'm saying most leaks would show in the simulator. They won't crash it because we have more RAM there but you'd be able to see them. You can use xcode's native memory monitoring tools with include source and probably do the same with Android's tools although I personally never had the need for that https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html

Comment: I'm seeing Runtime.totalMemory returning close to the whole RAM on the iOS devices I have, two iPod Touches: an iPod 4,1, and iPod 5,1.  This is  for a hello world style app, with no images other than those included in the flat blue theme.  Is this normal?

Comment: I would guess that it is but again this isn't very reliable. The only truly reliable thing about iOS RAM is the memory warning we get when we run low... Once we get that we force the GC to run and clean up.